# Do Moltres and Articuno exist in Pokemon Leaf Green?

Tags: pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green

I just lost Zapdos, after it got poisoned by my Nidoking and the Ultra ball didn't even stand a chance with it!

So, I wonder, do Moltres and Articuno exist in Pokemon Leaf Green?

---

I can imagine that the info is already in the Internet, but I fear it will reveal their location as well. I do not want that to happen, I want to explore, in order to find them. For example, some people in the game talked about these legendary birds, and I guy in the cycling road told me he caught his Voltorb in the Power Plant... ;)

Comment: You can try to catch Zapdos again when you have a savegame before "speaking" to the bird and turning the device off and on.

Comment: I know @h0ch5tr4355, but the rush was big enough to make me forget about it! ;)

Comment: In Pokemon X if you killed a legendary pokémon by accident you can battle it again after you do the elite four one time. I don't know if this is also the case in LeafGreen

Comment: I don't think so @IvoBeckers, back then, being legendary meant something! ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, all three legendary birds (Articuno, Zapdos and Moltres) exist in Pokemon Leaf Green.

If you get stuck, I've put their locations in the spoiler sections below. Mouse over them (tap on mobile) to view it.

**Articuno:**

> **Seafoam Islands** (off Route 20)

**Moltres:**

> **Mt Ember**, on 'One Island' in the Sevii Islands.

**Zapdos:**

> **Power Plant**, down from the entrance to Rock Tunnel.

---

It's also worth noting that

> Moltres'

location differs from the original Red & Blue games.

Comment: Do you know any way to get tips about them, like the "I caught a Voltorb in the Power Plant?"...Hmm, I wonder where the could be!!!

Comment: I can't remember any specific NPC's hints, but I'm sure there are some. If you just generally try to explore everywhere and talk to/battle every NPC you meet, you'll come across their locations easily enough :)

Comment: Just right now a girl in the sea told me that "there is a cavern underneath this island"...Articuno is that you?????? Thank you man!

Comment: @gsamaras No problem :) Happy hunting!